# Counting occurrence of 'every' number in array

Tags: java

So far, I only get the part where I can count one particular value in an array array. However, I would like to know how to get occurrence of  'every' number in an array and display them.

Here is the code I've got -

```
public class CIS3618thAssignment
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[100];

    for(int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
    {
        randomNumbers[index] = (int) (Math.random()*100);
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(randomNumbers[index]);
    }
    System.out.println("Occurrence of 2 is " + GetOccurrence(2, randomNumbers, 0, randomNumbers.length));
}
public static int GetOccurrence(int k, int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if(endIndex<startIndex)
        return 0;
    if(numbers[startIndex]>k)
        return 0;
    if(numbers[endIndex]<k)
        return 0;
    if(numbers[startIndex]==k && numbers[endIndex]==k)
        return endIndex-startIndex +1;

    int midInd = (startIndex+endIndex)/2;
    if(numbers[midInd]==k)
        return 1+GetOccurrence(k, numbers, startIndex, midInd-1) +     GetOccurrence(k, numbers, midInd+1,endIndex);
    else if(numbers[midInd]>k)
    return GetOccurrence(k, numbers, startIndex, midInd-1);
else
    return GetOccurrence(k, numbers, midInd+1, endIndex);
 }
}
```

So, in the source code, I am only capable of getting the occurrence of the `value = 2` out of the array.

Comment: can you show your expected result?

Comment: my expected result would be something like                                            " 0 appears 8 times in random integer array
  1 appears 15 times in random integer array"
Etc…up to  100

Comment: Binary search is designed to find position of specified value, not to count occurrences of every value in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this DEMO.](https://ideone.com/Zp9AHF)

I guess is what you want...

I didn't use `Map` or recursion as in your code, important for-loop to count is this one:

```
int[] results = new int[100];

// fill map with results
for(int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
{
    // if number on randomnumbers is 2, this line sum +1 in position 2 of the array
    results[randomNumbers[index]] = results[randomNumbers[index]] + 1;
}
```

Comment: Great to hear that @AndrewJones if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

By reading your codes, it seems that you are trying to find the element by binary search?  But you know that binary search works on sorted array. I didn't see the sorting part in your codes.

For your requirement, why not just build a `Map<Integer,Integer>` the key is the number, the value is the occurrence? It makes your implementation a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HashMap, where key is given number and value is number of occurrences.

You iterate over array and if the key(number) already exists, increment value(occurrences). Else, add new key and set its value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in the loop:

```
System.out.println("Occurrence of 2 is " + GetOccurrence(2, randomNumbers, 0, randomNumbers.length));
```

And change it as follows:

```
for(int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++) {
    System.out.println("Occurrence of " + randomNumbers[index] + " is " + GetOccurrence(randomNumbers[index], randomNumbers, 0, randomNumbers.length));
}
```

Comment: What is the error? And did you place it inside the loop?

Comment: oh so I put that entire line in another for loop and gives me an error that I don't know why

Comment: What is the error? Exception? What is the message that you're getting?

Comment: well so the lines in read in output are "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100",  "at cis3618thassignment.CIS3618thAssignment.GetOccurrence(CIS3618thAssignment.java:30)",  "at cis3618thassignment.CIS3618thAssignment.main(CIS3618thAssignment.java:20)
Java Result: 1".

Comment: This exception means that an object is being accessed outside of the arrays limits, which seems improbable, since the for loop starts at 0 and ends at 99, it never reaches 100. As for where its occurring, this exception is occurring in the GetOccurrence method and I'm guessing it has something to do with the increments to the index in that method.